# How did my github password reached the mac keygen?

Tags: macos, github

I remember logging to my git account using browser.

Also, I cloned repo to on my mac (private repo) and entered credentials at that time. Did that set the GitHub password in my keygen automatically?

OR, did it somehow get setup when I logged in using my browser.

Tired of scratching my head in understanding how it got there.

New to Mac.

Thanks

Comment: How a Mac works is not programming.

Answer (score 1):

We can only guess for you, here is one option:

Safari can, with your permission, store passwords in the keychain. Check Safari Preferences -> Passwords, if your password is listed there that's probably how it entered the keychain. You can remove it from the list if you wish.

Keep having an inquiring mind!

Comment: thanks for your reply. i did not use Safari. used Safari just once, that was to install Chrome.

Comment: As far as I know Chrome only stores the password to your passwords in the keychain. Seems to rule out the browser as the source. Happy hunting!